# Force new autoincrement column into column 0 after DataTable is Loaded

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, auto-increment

I need to add my own hidden autoincrement into a DataTable, but after the DataTable is loaded from an .accdb file.  There's no problem making the new column hidden, but is it possible to insert a column at position 0?  I can't place the new autoincrement column at the far right after the data is loaded because it would get in the way, because it would result in a gap before other columns are added during run-time.  Every data column whose column index>0 must be congruential with data, no gaps due to a hidden autoincrement column.

I know how to create a table from a DataView using the column names, but am not sure if that is what I want.  Will a new DataTable form a DataView be an intact stand-alone DataTable?

Comment: Are you loading a DB Table into a .Net DataTable object already? -- You can add a new Column and assign whatever display Index / Name  you prefer. The new Column can be auto-incrementing, with whatever seed and increment value you want. It can also be the PK, if the Table doesn't have one already and its loaded. What problem have you found implementing it? Do you have any code you have tried? -- Not sure what the DataView is for.

Answer (score 0):

To set the index value for any column after data have loaded, use the [DataColumn.SetOrdinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataColumn_SetOrdinal_System_Int32_) method.

Assume the data loaded has columns "ID"(primary key), "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3".

Next, add your own autoincrement, unique column as "myID", and then use the following syntax:

```
dataTable.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(1);
dataTable.Columns["Col 1"].SetOrdinal(2); 
dataTable.Columns["Col 2"].SetOrdinal(3);
dataTable.Columns["Col 3"].SetOrdinal(4); 
dataTable.Columns["myID"].SetOrdinal(0);
```

which will set the index of the newly added column to 0, and shift the rest up by one.

Comment: **Before** the data has been loaded, if you want to auto-increment feature to apply automatically.